# Composer update :Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: laravel, migration, composer-php, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I am upgrading the project from laravel 5.3 to laravel 5.4 and went through every documentation available on line. everything working fine but when I do composer update I am getting following error message.
 **[the error message]**

> Loading composer repositories with package information Updating
>   dependencies (including require-dev)
>
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.
>
> > Problem 1
>
> ```
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.24
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.23
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.22
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.21
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.20
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.19
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.18
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.17
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.16
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.15
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.14
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.13
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.12
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.11
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.10
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.9
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.8
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.7
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.6
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.5
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.4
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.3
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.2
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.1
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.4.0
>
>
> - barryvdh/laravel-async-queue v0.4.2 requires illuminate/support 5.0.x|5.1.x|5.2.x|5.3.x -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev].
> - barryvdh/laravel-async-queue v0.4.0 requires illuminate/support 5.0.x|5.1.x -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev].
> - barryvdh/laravel-async-queue v0.4.1 requires illuminate/support 5.0.x|5.1.x|5.2.x -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev].
> - barryvdh/laravel-async-queue v0.4.2 requires illuminate/support 5.0.x|5.1.x|5.2.x|5.3.x -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[5.0.x-dev, 5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev].
> - don't install illuminate/support 5.0.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 5.4.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 5.4.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support 5.2.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 5.4.x-dev
> - don't install illuminate/support 5.3.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 5.4.x-dev
> - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.4.* >satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.4.x-dev, v5.4.0, v5.4.1, v5.4.10, v5.4.11,
> ```
>
> v5.4.12, v5.4.13, v5.4.14, v5.4.15, v5.4.16, v5.4.17, v5.4.18,
>    v5.4.19, v5.4.2, v5.4.20, v5.4.21, v5.4.22, v5.4.23, v5.4.24, v5.4.3, v5.4.4, v5.4.5, v5.4.6, v5.4.7, v5.4.8, v5.4.9].
>
> ```
> - Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-async-queue 0.4.x -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-async-queue[v0.4.0, v0.4.1, v0.4.2].
> ```
>
> The composer.json file looks like this
>
> ```
> {
> "name": "laravel/laravel",
> "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
> "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
> "license": "MIT",
> "type": "project",
> "minimum-stability": "dev",
> "prefer-stable": true,
>
> "require": {
>     "php": ">=5.6.4",
>     "toin0u/geocoder-laravel": "@stable",
>     "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
>     "illuminate/support": "5.4.x",
>     "illuminate/console": "5.4.x",
>     "symfony/process": "~3.2",
>     "barryvdh/laravel-async-queue": "0.4.x",
>     "laravelcollective/html": "5.4.x-dev"
> },
> "require-dev": {
>     "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
>     "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
>     "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.7",
>     "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
>     "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*",
>     "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.1"
> },
> "autoload": {
>     "classmap": [
>         "database",
>         "app/Models",
>         "database/migrations",
>         "database/seeds",
>         "app/libraries"
>     ],
> "psr-4": {
>         "App\\": "app/"
>     }
> },
>
>  "extra": {
>     "branch-alias": {
>         "dev-master": "0.6-dev"
>     }
> },
>
> "autoload-dev": {
>     "classmap": [
>         "tests/TestCase.php"
>     ]
> },
> "scripts": {
>     "post-root-package-install": [
>         "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
>     ],
>     "post-create-project-cmd": [
>         "php artisan key:generate"
>     ],
>     "post-install-cmd": [
>         "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
>         "php artisan optimize"
>     ],
>     "post-update-cmd": [
>         "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
>         "php artisan optimize"
>     ]
> },
> "config": {
>     "preferred-install": "dist"
> } }
> ```

I have done composer install before updating it so that all the dependencies are downloaded.
To fix another error I have made a small change in require of **composer.lock file**

```
"packages": [
    {
        "name": "barryvdh/laravel-async-queue",
        "version": "v0.4.2",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-async-queue.git",
            "reference": "5b425bb2ce55f9ccfc0db4c52424936aed3641a9"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/barryvdh/laravel-async-queue/zipball/5b425bb2ce55f9ccfc0db4c52424936aed3641a9",
            "reference": "5b425bb2ce55f9ccfc0db4c52424936aed3641a9",
            "shasum": ""
        },

 "require": {
            "illuminate/console": "5.0.x|5.1.x|5.2.x|5.3.x|5.4.x",
            "illuminate/support": "5.0.x|5.1.x|5.2.x|5.3.x|5.4.x",
            "php": ">=5.4.0",
            "symfony/process": "~2.6|~3.0"
        },
```

I am not able to remove above error saying your requirements could not be resolved. Please help me ,Thanks in advance.

Comment: What PHP version are you running? Type php -v on the command line and if it is < 5.6.4, that is most likely your problem.

Comment: @RobFonseca sir I don't think so as I am using the version of  PHP 7.0.15 .which is latest version of PHP.

Comment: Hi @sameer you are using package `barryvdh/laravel-async-queue` with version `0.4.x`. I think for *Laravel 5.4* you have to use `0.6.x` version of this package. I think this may help you.

Comment: @LuckySaini sir I tried it by changing the version to both 0.5.0 and 0.6.x but nothing worked . still getting same error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked for me,

> Don't change the composer.lock file.

The first error output suggests that you were attempting to get the `0.4.x` version of `barryvdh/laravel-async-queue` **which does not work with Laravel 5.4.**

If all else fails, backup your composer.lock and re-run composer install.